# How to clip non-closed geometry

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

### Intro

I noticed an issue while implementing clipping (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25550384/1997232)).

> It looks like UIElement.Clip still render invisible parts

Rendering relatively small geometry (lines to only *fill* 1920x1200 area ~ 2000 vertical lines) take a lot of time. When using `Clip` and *moving* that geometry offscreen (so that clipping should remove significant part of it) it is still take *same* time (around 1 sec).

Ok, I found what using `Geometry.Combine` will do a clip (render time is reduced proportionally to removed after clipping geometry). Perfect!

### Problem

`Geometry.Combine` doesn't work with non-closed geometry properly. It produce closed geometry. And it looks ugly, connecting first and last point:

[image: Ugly sin(x)]

### Question

How can I perform clipping (reducing amount of geometry to be rendered) for non-closed figures?

### Edit

Here is geometry before (small peace of shown on picture)

> {M0;50L0;50L1;53,1395259764657L2;56,2666616782152L3;59,3690657292862L4;62,4344943582427L5;65,4508497187474L6;68,4062276342339L7;71,2889645782536L8; ...

and after

> {F1M54,9999923706055;34,5491371154785L53,9999885559082;37,5655174255371 53,0000114440918;40,6309471130371 52,0000076293945;43,7333335876465 ...

Notice change at beginning, was `M 0;50 L ...`, become `F 1 M 55;34 L ...`

[`F1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx) means `NonZero` filling

> Rule that determines whether a point is in the fill region of the path by drawing a ray from that point to infinity in any direction and then examining the places where a segment of the shape crosses the ray. Starting with a count of zero, add one each time a segment crosses the ray from left to right and subtract one each time a path segment crosses the ray from right to left. After counting the crossings, if the result is zero then the point is outside the path. Otherwise, it is inside.

And I have absolutely no clue what that means. But maybe it is important?

### Edit

I should have been looking at the end of strings. There is `z` at the end of `Path.Data`, which means figure is closed.

Strangely enough, trying to remove `z` (by using `Geometry.ToString()`/`Geometry.Parse()` combo) doesn't works. After some investigation I found what `Combine` produces physically enclosing figures (commands `L x;y`, where `x;y` is the leftmost point). And the worst thing is what it's not always the last point, so simply removing last `L x;y` before parsing doesn't works either. =(

### Edit

Sample to demonstrate problem:

Xaml:

```
<Path x:Name="path" Stroke="Red"/>
```

Code:

```
var geometry1 = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(100, 100, 100, 100));
var geometry2 = new PathGeometry(new[] { new PathFigure(new Point(0,0), new[] {
    new LineSegment(new Point(300, 300), true),
    new LineSegment(new Point(300, 0), true),
}, false) });

//path.Data = geometry1;
//path.Data = geometry2;
//path.Data = Geometry.Combine(geometry1, geometry2, GeometryCombineMode.Intersect, null);
```

Pictures of `geometry1` and `geometry2`:

[image] [image]

Resulting `Combine`:

[image]

As you can see 2 lines become 3 after clipping, debugging proves it:

> {F1M100;100L200;100 200;200 100;100z}

Notice, it's not only `z`, but also `100;100` point at the end, connecting starting point.

Comment: could you also share some working code for the same issue?

Comment: ok, allow me some time for the same. it's bit late here, hope you won't mind if I reply by tomorrow.

Comment: Geometry.Combine creates a shape not a path (to my understanding of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometrycombinemode(v=vs.110).aspx) and you cannot create a shape out of a path without closing it (see your result) i do not know if there is a given method to merge the geometrys, but i think geometry.Combine is the wrong start.

Comment: @SebastianL Take a look at the return type of the [`Geometry.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms607449.aspx) method. It does not create a Shape, but actually a `PathGeometry`. However, that doesn't mean that `Combine` would not automatically close the resulting geoemetry, and hence is the wrong approach here.

Comment: @Clemens how do achieve mathematically the result of an intersect of multiple nonclosed geometry?

Comment: apologies for the long delay, I totally forget about this question. I have an idea to solve the closed figure issue. so if you can flash a real geometry sample, let's  see if the idea can work.

Comment: @pushpraj, see last edit. In practice path could be more complicated than just 2 lines of course. I need general solution for *any* path if possible.

Comment: my idea is to convert `{F1M100;100L200;100 200;200 100;100z}` to `{M100;100L200;100 200;200 }` and parse it back to a geometry. what so you think? whole idea is to remove the begin figure `F1`, last point `100;100` and the close figure `z` from the string and parse it back to a path geometry.

Comment: @pushpraj, I tried that (see edits). Key is: *it's not always the last point*. Removing `z` and last point is simply not enough. Take example from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25450979/1997232) question, it really looks strange how `Combine` works for `sin(x)` and `RectangleGeometry`, even if it fits (no clipping).

Comment: how about removing last point from every figure and un-closing the same, see http://pastebin.com/41rC7wQr . currently for PolyLineSegment, may need to implement for others if seems feasible.

Comment: @pushpraj, Could you please test it with more complex `geometry2`? To example, `y = 50 * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI / 100 * x) + 50` and `x` ranges from `0` to `200`. It's sort of one on the picture I posted in this question. It may works ok for first few points, but will it works for a whole range (even assuming it will be clipped into big enough `RectangleGeometry`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60699/discussion-between-pushpraj-and-sinatr).

Answer (score 2):

I attempted to implement a clipping solutions for non closed geometry based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746274/line-intersection-with-aabb-rectangle) line intersection algorithm

**Code**

```
    public static PathGeometry ClipGeometry(PathGeometry geom, Rect clipRect)
    {
        PathGeometry clipped = new PathGeometry();
        foreach (var fig in geom.Figures)
        {
            PathSegmentCollection segments = new PathSegmentCollection();
            Point lastPoint = fig.StartPoint;
            foreach (LineSegment seg in fig.Segments)
            {
                List<Point> points;
                if (LineIntersectsRect(lastPoint, seg.Point, clipRect, out points))
                {
                    LineSegment newSeg = new LineSegment(points[1], true);
                    PathFigure newFig = new PathFigure(points[0], new[] { newSeg }, false);
                    clipped.Figures.Add(newFig);
                }
                lastPoint = seg.Point;
            }
        }
        return clipped;
    }

    static bool LineIntersectsRect(Point lineStart, Point lineEnd, Rect rect, out List<Point> points)
    {
        points = new List<Point>();

        if (rect.Contains(lineStart) && rect.Contains(lineEnd))
        {
            points.Add(lineStart);
            points.Add(lineEnd);
            return true;
        }

        Point outPoint;
        if (Intersects(lineStart, lineEnd, rect.TopLeft, rect.TopRight, out outPoint))
        {
            points.Add(outPoint);
        }

        if (Intersects(lineStart, lineEnd, rect.BottomLeft, rect.BottomRight, out outPoint))
        {
            points.Add(outPoint);
        }

        if (Intersects(lineStart, lineEnd, rect.TopLeft, rect.BottomLeft, out outPoint))
        {
            points.Add(outPoint);
        }

        if (Intersects(lineStart, lineEnd, rect.TopRight, rect.BottomRight, out outPoint))
        {
            points.Add(outPoint);
        }

        if (points.Count == 1)
        {
            if (rect.Contains(lineStart))
                points.Add(lineStart);
            else
                points.Add(lineEnd);
        }

        return points.Count > 0;
    }

    static bool Intersects(Point a1, Point a2, Point b1, Point b2, out Point intersection)
    {
        intersection = new Point(0, 0);

        Vector b = a2 - a1;
        Vector d = b2 - b1;
        double bDotDPerp = b.X * d.Y - b.Y * d.X;

        if (bDotDPerp == 0)
            return false;

        Vector c = b1 - a1;
        double t = (c.X * d.Y - c.Y * d.X) / bDotDPerp;
        if (t < 0 || t > 1)
            return false;

        double u = (c.X * b.Y - c.Y * b.X) / bDotDPerp;
        if (u < 0 || u > 1)
            return false;

        intersection = a1 + t * b;

        return true;
    }
```

currently solution works for line based geometry, other types perhaps need to be included if needed.

**test xaml**

```
<UniformGrid Columns="2"
             Margin="250,250,0,0">
    <Grid>
        <Path x:Name="pathClip"
              Fill="#22ff0000" />
        <Path x:Name="path"
              Stroke="Black" />

    </Grid>
    <Path x:Name="path2"
          Margin="100,0,0,0"
          Stroke="Black" />
</UniformGrid>
```

**test code 1**

```
    void test()
    {
        var geometry = new PathGeometry(new[] { new PathFigure(new Point(0,0), new[] {
                                                    new LineSegment(new Point(300, 300), true),
                                                    new LineSegment(new Point(300, 0), true),
                                                }, false) });

        Rect clipRect= new Rect(10, 10, 180, 180);
        path.Data = ClipGeometry(geometry, clipRect);
        path2.Data = geometry;
        pathClip.Data = new RectangleGeometry(clipRect);
    }
```

result

[image: result]

**test code 2**

```
    void test()
    {
        var radius = 1.0;
        var figures = new List<LineSegment>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++, radius += 0.1)
        {
            var segment = new LineSegment(new Point(radius * Math.Sin(i), radius * Math.Cos(i)), true);
            segment.Freeze();
            figures.Add(segment);
        }
        var geometry = new PathGeometry(new[] { new PathFigure(figures[0].Point, figures, false) });

        Rect clipRect= new Rect(10, 10, 180, 180);
        path.Data = ClipGeometry(geometry, clipRect);
        path2.Data = geometry;
        pathClip.Data = new RectangleGeometry(clipRect);
    }
```

result

[image: result]

give it a try and see how close it is.

Answer (score 0):

If i am right your mainquestion is:"How do i improve the performance of drawing many shapes?"

To get this working you have to understand `Geometry Math`.

Geometric objects can only merged/combined if they connect or overlap. And there is a big difference between path-geometry and shape-geometry.

As example if two circle overlap you can combine them in WPF

- to get the overlapping region: `Intersect`
- to get the difference: `Xor`
- to get the combined surface: `Union`
- to get the difference of only one shape: `Exclude`

For path-geometry it's a little different, because a path has no surface a path cannot `Intersect` | `Xor` | `Union` | `Exclude` another path or shape.

But WPF thinks you just forgot to close the path and is doing that for you, which result in the given result in your question.

so to achieve a performanceboost you have to filter all the geometry first for shapes and paths.

```
foreach(Shape geometryObj in ControlsOrWhatEver)
{
    if(geometryObj  is Line || geometryObj  is Path || geometryObj  is Polypath)
    {
        pathList.Add(geometryObj);
    } 
    else
    {
        shapeList.Add(geometryObj);
    }
}
```

for the shapeList you can use `Geometry.Combine`, but for the pathList you have to do some other work. You have to check if the connect at some point, doesnt matter if beginningPoint, endPoint or somwhere inbetween.
If you have done that you can Merge not Combine the path by yourself like:

```
public Polyline mergePaths(Shape line1, Shape line2)
{
     if(!checkLineType(line1) || !checkLineType(line2))
     {
         return null;
     }

     if(hitTest(line1, line2))
     {
         //here you have to do some math to determine the overlapping points
         //on these points you can do something like this:

         foreach(Point p in Overlapping Points)
         {
              //add the first line until p then add line2 and go on to add lin 1 until another p
         }
     }
     else
     {
         return null;
     }         
}
```

Comment: My original question is still *"How to clip non-closed geometry"*. Which you correctly call *path*. I see your point now better, than from comment, thanks. Your answer gave me idea to try to make that *path* a *geometry*, so instead of 2 lines I'll have to generate more (to example, two times thin lines forward and backward). Or even try to use *fake shadow* technique (enclosed figure and then another one, shifted by few pixels) to intersect closed geometry **after** clipping. Still, doesn't looks like a good solution.. if there is one at all exists..