# How to unfreeze frozen figure

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say, I have combined 2 geometries

```
var combined = Geometry.Combine(geometry1, geometry2, GeometryCombineMode.Intersect, null);
if (combined.Figures.Count > 0)
    combined.Figures[0].IsClosed = false; // throws exception
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot set a property on object 'M0;50,.....z' because it is in a read-only state.

In debugger

```
geometry1.IsFrozen = false;
geometry2.IsFrozen = false;
combined.IsFrozen = false;
combined.Figures.IsFrozen = false;
combined.Figures[0].IsFrozen = true; // wtf?
```

What would be the proper way to **unfreeze** that figure?

I am trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25563953/1997232) issue.

Comment: Is this a new issue or is this an update to your original question? if the latter, then you would be better to update that question.

Comment: @Sayse, yes and yes. It's separate issue, which may (I don't know yet) resolve my original problem. There could be possible *other* solutions to original question, that's why I decide to make a new question, which address more specific problem.

Comment: unfreezing is not an option, you may perhaps assign a new updated copy.

Comment: @pushpraj, any idea of how to do it? I can't find `Parse` or `Copy` methods.

Comment: many classes provide clone method. so if you can tell what is the actual need to do the same, may I try to suggest some workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pushpraj commented, there is a `Clone()` method to deal with the problem:

```
var combined = Geometry.Combine(geometry1, geometry2, GeometryCombineMode.Intersect, null);
if (combined.Figures.Count > 0)
{
    var figure = combined.Figures[0].Clone();
    figure.IsClosed = false;
    combined.Figures.RemoveAt(0);
    combined.Figures.Insert(0, figure);
}
```