# Geometry.Combine gives odd result on intersecting geometry objects

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, geometry, pathgeometry

I have this two geometries:

```
StreamGeometry geo1 = Geometry.Parse("M590202.895,5958727.621L590280.305,5958747.961L590337.012,5958762.785L590337.172,5958763.234L590337.412,5958763.914L590280.065,5958748.931L590241.24,5958738.726L590202.576,5958728.98z");
```

which looks like this

[image: geo1]

and

```
StreamGeometry geo2 = Geometry.Parse("M590241.24,5958738.726L590280.195,5958748.551L590337.172,5958763.234L590337.412,5958763.914L590280.065,5958748.931L590241.24,5958738.726z");
```

which looks like this:
[image: geo2]

When I look at these objects in a GIS system `geo2` is fully contained in `geo1` in the upper right corner:

[image: Both geometries together]

When I get the intersection of both by

```
PathGeometry intersection = PathGeometry.Combine(geo1, geo2, GeometryCombineMode.Intersect, null);
```

I get

```
{F1M590241,25;5958738,5L590280,1875;5958748,5 590332,3125;5958762 590337;5958763 590337,1875;5958763 590337,4375;5958764 590280,0625;5958749 590241,25;5958738,5z}
```

which looks quite strange:

[image]

In detail there are irritating discrepancies. For example at the right end the red marked `intersection` geometrie isn't at all, what I was expecting.

[image: upper right corner with discrepancies]

I tried `Combine`with different tolerance values, but with no effect to the result.

What's going wrong here?

*** Update ***
I closed the geometries as @Sinatr supposed and simplified the first one by leaving out the left part of it. Both doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: I think it's [non-closing intersection geometry problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25563953/1997232). Because of it I switch to GDI+ in wpf. Can you produce enclosed geometry? Remove last point and put there `Z` instead.

Comment: So you think the problem might be caused because the first point is added as last point instead of telling PathGeometry to close the geometry? Great idea, can't wait to see if this will change the problem!

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks for the suggestion. Closing the geometries did not change the result. I updated the question though.

Answer (score 0):

We were in contact with Microsoft regarding this issue. The problem here is, that the WPF `Geometry` objects are designed for visualisation purposes. So the can't handle very large coordinates like we did here.
The recommended way is to use [SqlGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.aspx). We have good results there.